# list the files of a directory and subdirectory recursively in Databricks(DBFS)

Tags: python-3.x, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

Using python/dbutils, how to display the files of the current directory & subdirectory recursively in Databricks file system(DBFS).

Comment: Use `walk` with a path similar to `/dbfs/mnt/my/mount/...` (and not `dbfs:/mnt/my/mount/...`  - mind the prefix)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Surprising thing about dbutils.fs.ls (and %fs magic command) is that it doesn't seem to support any recursive switch. However, since ls function returns a list of FileInfo objects it's quite trivial to recursively iterate over them to get the whole content, e.g.:

```py
def get_dir_content(ls_path):
  dir_paths = dbutils.fs.ls(ls_path)
  subdir_paths = [get_dir_content(p.path) for p in dir_paths if p.isDir() and p.path != ls_path]
  flat_subdir_paths = [p for subdir in subdir_paths for p in subdir]
  return list(map(lambda p: p.path, dir_paths)) + flat_subdir_paths
    

paths = get_dir_content('/databricks-datasets/COVID/CORD-19/2020-03-13')
[print(p) for p in paths]
```

Comment: you could also use `%ls -R <path>`

Answer (score 11):

An alternative implementation can be done with generators and `yield` operators. You have to use at least `Python 3.3+` for `yield from` operator and check out this [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) for a better understanding of `yield` operator:

```py
def get_dir_content(ls_path):
    for dir_path in dbutils.fs.ls(ls_path):
        if dir_path.isFile():
            yield dir_path.path
        elif dir_path.isDir() and ls_path != dir_path.path:
            yield from get_dir_content(dir_path.path)
    
list(get_dir_content('/databricks-datasets/COVID/CORD-19/2020-03-13'))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also try this recursive function:

```
def lsR(path):
    return [
        fname
        for flist in [
            ([fi.path] if fi.isFile() else lsR(fi.path))
            for fi in dbutils.fs.ls(path)
        ]
        for fname in flist
    ]


lsR("/your/folder")
```

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.

Comment: I will gladly do it, but I'm not sure what kind of explanation would you expect?
lsR() should return a list of file names so:
1. part1: [([fi.path] if fi.isFile() else lsR(fi.path)) for fi in dbutils.fs.ls(path)] builds a list of lists.
 For each result of dbutils.fs.ls
  If fi is a file
   it puts list with only one item
  else if fi is a directory
   it calls recursively lsR() to get list of file names
2. Then the part1 is "unpacked" by double comprehension
  [fname for flist in <part1> for fname in flist]
 This changes [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']] into ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Answer (score 0):

There are other answers listed here, but it worth noting that databricks stores datasets as folders.

For example, you might have a 'directory' called `my_dataset_here`, which contains files like this:

```
my_dataset_here/part-00193-111-c845-4ce6-8714-123-c000.snappy.parquet
my_dataset_here/part-00193-123-c845-4ce6-8714-123-c000.snappy.parquet
my_dataset_here/part-00193-222-c845-4ce6-8714-123-c000.snappy.parquet
my_dataset_here/part-00193-444-c845-4ce6-8714-123-c000.snappy.parquet
...
```

There will be **thousands of these such files** in a typical set of tables.

Attempting to enumerate every single file in such a folder can take a very long time... like, minutes, because the single call to `dbutils.fs.ls` must return an array of every single result.

Therefore, a naive approach such as:

```
stack = ["/databricks-datasets/COVID/CORD-19/2020-03-13"]
while len(stack) > 0:
  current_folder = stack.pop(0)
  for file in dbutils.fs.ls(current_folder):
    if file.isDir():
      stack.append(file.path)
      print(file.path)
    else:
      print(file.path)
```

Will indeed list every file, but it will also take forever to finish. In my test environment, enumerating over 50 odd tables took **8 minutes**.

However, the new 'delta' format, if used, creates a standard named folder called '_delta_log' inside delta table folders.

We can therefore modify our code to check each folder to see if it is a dataset before attempting to enumerate the entire contents of the folder:

```
stack = ["/databricks-datasets/COVID/CORD-19/2020-03-13"]
while len(stack) > 0:
  current_folder = stack.pop(0)
  for file in dbutils.fs.ls(current_folder):
    if file.isDir():
      # Check if this is a delta table and do not recurse if so!
      try:
        delta_check_path = f"{file.path}/_delta_log"
        dbutils.fs.ls(delta_check_path)  # raises an exception if missing
        print(f"dataset: {file.path}")
      except:            
        stack.append(file.path)
        print(f"folder: {file.path}")
    else:
        print(f"file: {file.path}")
```

This code runs on the same test environment in **38 seconds**.

In trivial situations, the naive solution is acceptable, but it quickly becomes totally unacceptable in real world situations.

Notice that this code will *only work* on delta tables; if you are using parquet/csv/whatever format, you're out of luck.